# How to select which labels to see on plot axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im plotting a dataset that looks like

```
month       number_of_lots
2015-02     6
2015-03     44
2015-04     117
2015-05     210
2015-06     389
2015-07     698
2015-08     866
2015-09     2517
2015-10     3420
2015-11     5081
       ...
```

`lots_per_month.plot(x='month', y='number_of_lots', grid=1)`

plot I get:
[image]

The problem is, matplotlib places 6 labels on X axis, I want to place labels where year maximum and minimum are, for instance.

Can I somehow  select manually which labels to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xticks` function. For example:

```
plt.plot(df.month, df.number_of_lots)
plt.xticks([3,8], ["number_3", "number_8"]) 
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Ive tried xticks, maybe I was doing something wrong

Comment: If it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer for future generations.